# Any reason why Ruby on Rails doesn't have a standard user authenticated system built in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, cakephp, frameworks, symfony1

This question aims to understand RoR and frameworks in general.  It looks like RoR never had any standard user authentication system.  Was it just historical reason (just happened naturally as it did)... or could it be intentional?  Because RoR is a website building tool, more often than not, user authentication is a crucial part of a website.

To put it into perspective, another question is, do other popular frameworks, Django, Symfony, CakePHP, have user authentication built in?

Comment: My experience with RoR is absolutely zero, but auth is not the sort of thing I would expect to see at the language level. There are many different ways to authenticate users, there's no point building any single one into the language.

Comment: @Mike This isn't the "language-level"; RoR, Django, Symfony, CakePHP, these are all frameworks, and authentication is something you might reasonably expect the framework to provide.

Comment: @meagar: Okay my bad. Like I said, I have never used it. My point still stands, though.

Comment: Django has auth built in and it's very convenient for getting up and running, but it's rigid. If your project reaches any maturity you'll spend time extending the auth app for your needs, or ripping it out. So I'm not surprised a web framework would leave auth to 3rd party libs. The framework can't ship anticipating all the use cases for auth.

Comment: Even though authenticated need can be different for any website, if there is a standard one that simply has the most basic functions built in, such as general user log in / log out / remember me cookie, and maybe an admin flag, then other gems or plugin can extend it or implement its own way. (assuming the standard one can easily be disabled)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reasonably generic way to do user authentication. Most frameworks leave it up to you to choose the plugin that most closely matches what you're trying to accomplish.

For example, consider these two situations:

- a blog which has a single administrator with password-protected admin-facing tools
- a site like YouTube which allows users to sign up and administer their own content

Both of these sites would require vastly different authentication systems; which of these systems should Rails cater to out-of-the-box?

Comment: true... though if there is at least a standard one (which can be disabled easily), then at least more books or blog posts can talk about how it works, how to modify it to your needs, etc).  Right now we have Restful Authentication, AuthLogic, Devise, and no book can talk much about one of them as the book doesn't want to lock in any one of them.  If there is a standard one, as least books or blog posts can dissect or analyze its code more in depth or compare any third party one like Devise to it more readily.

Comment: @動靜能量 That's what we have Railscasts for! Search for any of those authentication systems and you'll find multiple screencasts for it.

Comment: @Mark the reason is, I don't find very good overview or documentation or API spec of Restful Authentication.  Railscast helps as it talks about how to use it.  But if I look at the docs of Restful Authentication it completely blows my mind, as half of the two line doc for `current_user` is: Future calls avoid the database because nil is not equal to false.

Answer (score 3):

The Rails core team wanted to ensure that Rails was open-ended enough to make anything you want. There is no one-size-fits-all authentication scheme, so the core team decided to leave it out. Rails is easily extendable via gems and plugins, so that is where they belong.

Some examples are [Warden](https://rubygems.org/gems/warden) and the [Rails Warden](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_warden) plugin, [Devise](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise), [Authlogic](https://rubygems.org/gems/authlogic), and [Restful Authentication](https://rubygems.org/gems/restful_authentication).

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP has a built in [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication) component that is  pretty straight forward and easy to implement.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: "To put it into perspective, another question is, do other popular frameworks, Django, Symfony, CakePHP, have user authentication built in?"  Seems to answer that part of the question.

Comment: I stand corrected. Forgive me for glossing over that ancillary question.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these frameworks you mentioned are toolkits, not complete products.  You build these things yourself, or leverage plugins from the community.  Django's admin plugin/module has authentication out of the box though.  Drupal does too, as a matter of fact.

Comment: More like 50%, not "most."  CakePHP and Symfony are full stack.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication can be(and is in my opinion) a matter of taste and need. If Rails was including things like that, it would start to become a website and not a framework. The programmer has to be free to choose among various implementations. That is why gems are available.

Answer (score 0):

I've been programming a little in Rails and CakePHP, and I can say that Rails doesn't need to provide a mechanism like this. The community is very very good, and there are many examples (already said, like Devise, Authlogic...) made by very good programmers. Of course, there are many tutorials online (and also, railscasts, which are simply awesome) to program a succesful set-up for your project. So, if we have all of this, why should we need something like cakePHP mechanism? It's OK, it works, but there's just a very good tutorial and that's all( and maybe enough..). So, in the end, if u have a nice community you shouldn't care about the core of the technology, there will be always someone else more experienced with your needs that will do it for you. And if you don't find it, do it by yourself and in the proccess you will find a lot of help! :)